# Access Truecrypt encrypted drive on network

Tags: windows-7, mount, truecrypt

I have a drive encrypted with Truecrypt that I want to allow accessed on a home network. I have it connected to the router, and the router shows that something is connected to it. However, it cannot access the drive, since I did not format the drive using windows and then truecrypt. I formatted only with truecrypt, so there is nothing the router can access. I cannot map the drive to a drive letter.

Is there any way to mount this drive while its connected to the router?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm taking it you have a router with a USB port that allows a drive to be shared over a network.

Unless you have Truecrypt running on the router itself, the router isn't going to know what to do with it.  It will treat it like an unformatted disk or a disk with an unrecognized filesystem.

Furthermore, Truecrypt works on the block level.  I'm betting your router basically has `samba` or something similar installed that implements Windows file sharing - hence your router is sharing on the file level.  So your other systems are connecting to the router's exposed samba/CIFS share.  This is vastly different than how Truecrypt accesses the drive.  Truecrypt cannot mount a volume via samba/CIFS.  (It does work over iSCSI - I won't get into it now but it won't work how you likely want it to work.)

If the router was running Truecrypt, then it could share the device by mounting the Truecrypt volume itself and then sharing that mounted volume over samba/CIFS.

You may want to setup a separate PC with Truecrypt installed and use that to share the device over the network.

Comment: how would i install truecrypt on my router?

Comment: It *may* be possible if you can flash the router with DD-WRT or other third-party firmware.  You would need to find an `ipkg` that someone would have happened to package up (or make one yourself) as well as any dependencies of Truecrypt.