# Network File/Media Server with encryption

Tags: hard-drive, partitioning, encryption, truecrypt, file-server

I am using an Asus RT-AC68U router and I just acquired an external HDD that I want to keep it plugged into the USB 3.0 port in order to expose data into my home network. I am looking for a way to keep data encrypted and also to make the content available to my command directly from that HDD, already connected to my router. The main reason I want to encrypt the HDD are the thieves in case somebody breaks my house and stole it. But I want to stream data from this external HDD to my smart TV, so my partition needs to be decrypted. In case a partition should be encrypted with a tool such TrueCrypt this would not be available by default or via Samba without file mounting and decryption.

In order to achieve this I am thinking to two realistic workarounds but I am not thanks-full with them:

- An open (non-encrypted) partition and keeping the sensitive data into
  an encrypted file container (ex. virtual encrypted disk via
  TrueCrypt).
- Two partitions: one encrypted and one "open" + copy the interest data
  on the open partition when it's needed.

But both solutions means a wasted disk space. Also, interferes with one additional idea that I want to get in practice: adding the important data stored on that HDD to an external cloud service.

The best idea would be finding a way to run a tool such TrueCrypt on my router that should allow encryption/decryption by command/scripts.
I have also a USB 2.0 port where I can plug-in a memory stick with a Linux distribution that might be available to decrypt my HDD data (ex. http://cryptonas.senselab.org/), but who will process the decryption?

Ideas? :)

PS. I know TrueCrypt is “deprecated”.

Answer (score 0):

I just found an similar [topic](https://superuser.com/a/479981/260913) and the solution I see in my case is finding an additional device connected to the router that should run TrueCrypt connected directly with the HDD (not sure if it's possible to run the TrueCrypt within the router).

Answer (score -1):

Perhaps it is an option to buy a HDD with internal hardware encryption.

I'm did not understand how you access the HDD from your PC. If you use CIFS, you can use Symantec PGP. This software can encryp files on network shares. You can define directories on a network share and configure which data will be encrypted and which not.

---

Have a look here:

http://www.digittrade.de/shop/index.php/cat/c22_Sicherheitsmedien.html

I have good experience with this HDDs

No, the PGP software encrypts each file, so you do not need to mount a virtual disk for accessing the encrypted files. This is much better for my point of view. Also many peoble may access these encrypted files, this is not realizable with TrueCrypt. Never-the-less depending on your requirements what is the best solution.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! 
I understand your point of view and I just want to add one advantage of TrueCrypt: "No TrueCrypt volume can be identified (volumes cannot be distinguished from random data). 
So, a thief would not know "what the hack" I have there. :)